# Subsets of a vector space that are convex and have convex complement.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, convex-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $F$.

Is there a characterization of the subsets $A$ that are convex and also have convex complement? Maybe when the dimension is finite it is possible?

I think that in $\mathbb R^n$ we can define it recursively, by using nested semihyperplanes.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a set in Euclidean space?

Comment: yes, in $\mathbb R^n$ any semihyperplane works, you can get more examples by taking a semihyperplane and removing a semihyperplane one dimension smaller from its "face".

Comment: Intuitively I'm tempted to say that in $\mathbb R^n$, those subsets are exactly the semihyperplanes (half spaces?).

Comment: Just realized I'm wrong, if $A=\mathbb R^n$, its complement is the empty set, and both are convex.

Comment: well, maybe plus that exception.

Comment: I think that for $\mathbb R^n$ we can do it via induction

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: I don't get your example: in $\Bbb R^3$ consider the axes: $x$ pointing to you, $y$ pointing to the right and $z$ pointing upwards. Remove the semihyperplane $H = \{(x, y, 0) \mid x \in \Bbb R, y \ge 0\}$. Can you join the points $(a,b,1)$ and $(a,b,-1)$, where $(a,b,0) \in H$? You can't, so the complementary of $H$ is not convex. Or maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "semihyperplane".

Comment: @AlexM. remove $H$ from what?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: From $\Bbb R^3$, naturally. $H$ is what you call $A$, and $\Bbb R^3 \setminus H$ is its complementary (which, as shown above, is not convex). Or are we having a serious misunderstanding here? (I'm asking all this in good faith, maybe I'm misinterpreting your words in some unintended way.)

Comment: no, I meant that you start with a closed hyperplane of dimension $3$,and then you take a way a closed hyperplance of dimension $2$ from the "face" of the first one, and then you can do the same in dimension $1$ etc.

Comment: Wait, I have a question. Does the notion of convexity make sense when the field $F$ is not $\mathbb R$? Afaik, convex combinations use real numbers as coefficients...?

Comment: @N.Bach: Indeed, for any two points we may talk about their affine combinations (the straight line determined by them), but not about their convex combinations (i.e. the line segment), because this would require the use of inequalities, i.e. a notion of "positive elements" in $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq R^n$ be a convex nonempty subset of $R^n$ whose complement is convex as well. Since $A \cap A^c = \emptyset$ by separation theorem , we can separate them by a nonzero hyperplane. Therefore $A$ covers completely one side of the hyperplane and $A^c$ does same job in the other side of hyperplane. The contribution of $A$ and $A^c$ **on the hyperplane** is same as question in one less dimension. Therefore to realize the characterization of such sets you need think recursively.

For examples in $R^2$ there are three types of a such this set, 1- $A= R^2$ ,  2- $A$ be closed half space,

3- $A$ be open half spaces $\cup$ half line

I think in $R^n$ we have $n+1$ different types of such set.